# Finding values for range of terms in a geometric sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometry, geometric-series

I am NOT math person. I'm a musician who needs some math help.

Given the following:

A1 = An / (r)^(n-1)

I know "An" and "r" and "n"; I want to find "A1" but only for a specific range of terms in the sequence.

Example:

A1 = 1000 / (2)^(n-1) where "n" represents every term from the 35th through the 45th term in the sequence.

How might that range of terms be illustrated in the equation?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome. I think you need a formula with a parameter like t which gives numbers 35 to 45, something like $n=f(t)$, am I right?

Comment: ,Also you must give the values of 36th and 45th terms.